# Set the active tenant on a resolved child scope

Tags: c#, autofac

Is there a way to set the active tenant on a child scope? I assumed it would have a global affect but it does not *after* the child scope (`ILifetimeScope`) has been resolved.

## Dependencies

```
<package id="Autofac" version="4.9.2" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Autofac.Multitenant" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
```

## Reproduction

Reproduction written using a .net framework console application and the above listed dependencies.

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Multitenant;

namespace ConsoleAutoFacTenants
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<GeneralReader>().As<IReader>().InstancePerDependency();
            var appContainer = builder.Build();

            var tenantIdentifier = new AutomationTenantStrategy();
            var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentifier, appContainer);

            mtc.ConfigureTenant("1", b => b.RegisterType<SpecificReader>().As<IReader>().InstancePerDependency());

            // expected
            var reader1 = mtc.Resolve<IReader>();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(reader1.Name == "General");

            // unexpected result in debug.assert, assumed that reader2 would resolve type SpecificReader
            var childScoped = mtc.BeginLifetimeScope();
            tenantIdentifier.TenantId = "1";
            var reader2 = childScoped.Resolve<IReader>();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(reader2.Name == "Specific");
        }
    }
    internal sealed class AutomationTenantStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
    {
        public object TenantId { get; set; }
        public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
        {
            var activeTenant = this.TenantId;
            if (TenantId == null)
            {
                tenantId = null;
                return false;
            }
            tenantId = activeTenant;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public interface IReader
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
    public sealed class GeneralReader : IReader
    {
        public string Name => "General";
    }
    public sealed class SpecificReader : IReader
    {
        public string Name => "Specific";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the factory ?

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements but it seems that the multitenant package won't let you do what you want easily. I would recommend you to look at the source code of the multitenant package, it is quite simple, and then create your own multitenant architecture based on your specifics needs. The package is great for simple case but a multitenant application is usually a large project. Having full control of how your multi-tenant works could be simpler and better than to *hack* this module.

Comment: @CyrilDurand - Thanks, I ended up registering a singleton instance that contained a reference to the `MultitenantContainer` (accessed as `ILifetimeScope`) and used that from my factory. I will mark your answer as correct as it seems that this is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you resolve a `ILifetimeScope` from a scope it will return itself and not create a child lifetimescope.

This line :

```
var childScoped = mtc.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
```

should be replaced by

```
var childScoped = mtc.BeginLifetimeScope();
```

When a new LifetimeScope is created the multitenant module will set the tenantId to the scope. In your sample you have to "change" the tenantId before the creation of the child LifetimeScope

```
tenantIdentifier.TenantId = "1";
var childScoped = mtc.BeginLifetimeScope();
```

The resolved `IReader` will then be the one specified for the tenant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was already aware that if I set the tenant id before I created a child scope it would work. Is there any way to update the child scope to use the set tenant id in the order I was trying though (or even force it globally across all existing scopes)?

Comment: As far as I remember. Tenant are implemented through tagged lifetime scope and thus can't be changed after creation. I tried once to once to use the *Autofac.Multitenant* package, I think it would be easier to consider it as a possible implementation but copy and adapt the code to your specific scenario

Comment: Maybe there is another way to skin this cat. This issue stems from a resolved factory that needs to create (resolve actually) services based on an incoming tenant id. I can inject the factory with `ILifetimeScope`, change the tenant id, and then resolve types but this is not working (hence the question). Is there a built in way to resolve the `MultitenantContainer`? If not I will create a wrapper around it or add it directly to the registry and resolve it that way as it seems that is what the factory needs a reference to in order for this design to work.

Comment: Also thank you for your help so far, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you update the question with the updated requirements ?